# Processor quality versus graphics card

Tags: rendering, cpu, graphics-card

I am planning to purchase a laptop which could run a complex software such a SolidWorks.

My friend advised me to go for a graphics card. However I am of the view that instead of investing in a graphics card, it is better to invest in a better processor. A better processor will help rendering as well as other computations. Please tell me if I am right on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

Both play an important role, but i'm going to say get the system with the better graphics

If its a laptop with a decent graphics card, chances are it isn't going to come with a terrible CPU. Modern CPUs *are* fairly powerful - a current generation core i5 is roughly as powerful as a previous generation one, (i don't really use AMD, but the same is likely true - an AMD box with a discrete graphics option isn't going to suck).

As for the direct effect of the graphics card, it depends - a quick check indicates that solidworks IS GPU accelerated, so getting a decent graphics option is a good idea - its more likely the discrete option will be supported.

Also, don't forget you can't 'just' swap out the graphics in a laptop - you're stuck with it (you can't upgrade the CPU either, but i'm supposing the CPU IS powerful enough).

I'd suspect the best system for this would be a gaming laptop, but your milage (and budget) may vary.

Comment: I would agree, but in the long run, the most important is the processor.

Comment: with a desktop, yes. with a laptop, i disagree. He needs to look at the whole package, since he's stuck with what he buys short of replacing the whole unit - in this case, the better GPU, will likely be part of a better system.

Comment: I have several companies, who are engineering firms, who use solidworks, and rendering using the CPU is more important. Actually, you brought up a point that crossed my mind: He SHOULD BUY a desktop if at all possible.

Comment: @journeyman I guess my usage of solidworks will be quit limited as I am a student having amateur interest in solidworks. I really dont think that I will be ever dealing with very highly sophisticated designs which may become a problem for a non GPU based coputer design.

Comment: @KCotreau You are absolutely right. In almost every case a desktop wins over a laptop with more features for less money. But I guess I will need to have a laptop as I require computing power on the go.

Comment: eh, looking at recommended system specs .. "Intel or AMD system" . On the other hand, they recommend certain graphics cards - none of which are mobile models. http://www.solidworks.com/sw/support/SystemRequirements.html . Still, my statement that, a system with a good graphics card is likely to be, on the whole, a good, system for this sort of thing stands.

Comment: @bubble That is why I said, "if at all possible". I realized that you really may need to take it with you.

Comment: @Journeyman i was looking at the configuration of various available inspiron models. I could find none with a dedicated graphics card. however they do have "Intel® HD Graphics 3000" (I dont know what that means). Will it be sufficient for an armature solidworks user like me?

Comment: Well, the intel HD graphics cards are about the same as a low end discrete card - it is much better than anything they used to have, but i have no idea how it'll do in solidworks. The sandy bridge platform for most part, is pretty good tho, its the first half decent integrated graphics that intel's put out IMO

Comment: done then i5 processor with this discrete graphics card.

Comment: the intel HD graphics is not discrete. its integrated. Its just not too bad. An AMD or NVIDIA would still probably do better tho

Comment: I guess it will be sufficient for me as I have to rarely use solidworks. Besides there if it can help me with any other application which you can think of, please let me know. I am EE student